# Use the implicit function theorem to prove that $f=f^{-1}$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem, inverse-function-theorem

I've had some problems to prove this proposition:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ a function of class $C^1$ such that $(f\circ f)(x_0)=x_0$ for some $x_0\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $Df(f(x))Df(x)=I_n$, for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, where $D$ denotes the derivative and $I_n$ the identy matrix of size $n$. Show that $f$ is invertible and $f=f^{-1}$.

Thanks.

Comment: And what did you get out of this application? Don't expect to get any help unless you show ALL your work. The people here are ready to assist as long as you help them do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that by the chain rule, $Df^2 \equiv I_n$. Thus, by Lagrange's mean value theorem,

$$
f^2(b) - f^2(a) = Df^2(b-a) = b-a \quad (\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}^n)
$$

In particular, since $f^2(x_0) = x_0$ and $f^2(b) - f^2(x_0) = b - x_0$, we can conclude that

$$
f^2(b) = b,
$$

that is, $f^2 \equiv id$. Thus, $f$ is its own left and right inverse. In particular, $f$ is injective: if $f(x) = f(y)$, then

$$
x = f^2(x) = f^2(y) = y.
$$

For a similar reason, we also get surjectivity: for each $p \in \mathbb{R}$,

$$
f(f(p)) = p.
$$

Finally, since this proves that $f$ is invertible, from $f^2 \equiv id$ we get that

$$
f \equiv f^{-1}
$$

by composing with $f^{-1}$ at both sides of the equation.

Comment: You could stop at the fact that $f^2=\text{id}$. In category theory thats the definition for a bijective function say $f$ i. e. a unique function $g$ such that $fg=gf=\text{id}$ (obviously with the corresponding $\text{id}$'s). And it can be show that in the common categorys (like $\text{Set}$, $\text{Grp}$...) this definition is equivalent to injective+surjective.

Comment: @HurjuiIonut yeah, this could definitely be less verbose, but since OP is learning multivariate calculus at the moment, I preferred to leave it as self contained as possible.

Comment: Cool, great job!

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's an interesting solution.